# .woff Icons Only Works on First Page Load in IE 11

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, font-face, custom-tags

We have a website which implements a custom font face.

This work every time in IE on our test server. When we move to production it works but only the first time it loads the page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fcgm.png) If I delete my temp internet file and reload the page it will work again.

I've used font squirrel to produce their so-called "bulletproof" css.
 here is my custom header code.

here is font-face code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?48s99');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?48s99#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?48s99') format('truetype'),
  url('fonts/icomoon.woff?48s99') format('woff'),
  url('fonts/icomoon.svg?48s99#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<customHeaders>
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains" />

   </customHeaders>
```

here is the image after reloading the page it throws 404 not found
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Cache Control is set to no-cache font-face will not work in IE after the first load. Try testing with caching on and off to help debug.

Comment: thanks, I tested that but it is still not working in IE on refresh.